С++ 14 Пропуск/расширение выделения памяти
Изучаю С++ 14 по документу, первая таблица Основные возможности языка C++14:
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/14
Сейчас остановился на пункте таблицы:
Пропуск/расширение выделения памяти
Причем напротив MSVS стоит пометка Н/Д
Почитав документ из таблицы:
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation
В котором говориться:
В случае объединения выделение, сделанное выражением new E1, может быть расширено, чтобы обеспечить дополнительное хранилище для другого выражения new E2, если все следующее верно:

...
E1 и E2 будут вызывать одну и ту же заменяемую глобальную функцию распределения (начиная с C++14)

Как я понял в пункте 2) описано то что дает документ здесь (пункт из таблицы):
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3664.html
Я хотел поинтересоваться - это изменение в С++14 Пропуск/расширение выделения памяти не касается MSVS потому что этот пункт про malloc() и realloc()? а не про new/delete из MSVS - то есть в других компиляторах new может повторять функции malloc()/realloc()? В других компиляторах (не MSVS) new может и выделять и изменять размер выделенной памяти одновременно?

Я так понял, что он N/A потому что MSVC настолько дубовый, что у них даже надежды нет это поддержать. Или желания. (См. сноску [E] здесь.) Где вы углядели свзять между malloc/new и MSVC - непонятно, эти функции же есть во всех компиляторах. И обратите внимание, что у GCC тоже написано N/A.

Так о чем это изменение С++14, я так понимаю что например можно комбинировать два оператора new для выделения памяти?

Да, комбинировать или вообще убирать в процессе оптимизации.

Так это забота компилятора или программиста - комбинировать new? Вы говорите - или вообще убирать в процессе оптимизации- это я так понимаю дело компилятора. Я так понял, например программист скомбинировал два оператора new а компилятор оптимизировал- сделал один new, правильно?

Не понял. Программист, конечно, может объединять и убирать что хочет. Тут речь про то, что компилятору разрешили это делать.
